# FFmpeg on iPhone getting error running 'make'

Tags: iphone, makefile, ffmpeg, configure

I'm getting an error when trying to make ffmpeg on my intel mac, iPhone SDK 3.1, using the same command lines that were used here, and using the latest checkout of ffmpeg from svn. Here's the error that I'm getting:

CC  libavcodec/apedec.o
AS  libavcodec/arm/dsputil_arm.o
/bin/sh: /usr/local/bin/gas-preprocessor.pl: Permission denied
make: *** [libavcodec/arm/dsputil_arm.o] Error 126

My gas-preprocessor.pl file is in /usr/local/bin..

Any ideas? I feel like I might be missing something really trivial here.  Why is gas-preprocessor throwing a permission denied?

Comment: At the risk of being obvious:  What are the permissions on gas-preprocessor.pl (`ls -l /usr/local/bin/gas-preprocessor.pl`, of course)?  What is in the `#!` line at the start of gas-preprocessor.pl?  What does the line in the makefile that is invoking this command look like?

Answer (score 0):

I had something like that before.
I copied the gas-preprocessor.pl to /usr/bin and it worked like a charm.

Good Luck!